# Grails Quartz plugin not remembering stateful data between job executions?

Tags: grails, groovy, quartz-scheduler, grails-plugin

I need to persist a counter value between executions of a Grails Quartz plugin job. This runs at the correctly timed intervals and I can set the jobDataMap and read the value back correctly (during the same execution run), but it refuses to remember it between between executions.

I've set `concurrent = false` as the docs advised. Any ideas? I just need to persist and increment a counter. I want to avoid using a DB if at all possible, I think this should just use memory? Or other work arounds?

My TestJob.groovy, in /server/grails-app/jobs:

```
package myPackage
class MyJob {
    static triggers = {
        simple repeatInterval: 5000l // execute job every 5 seconds
    }

    def concurrent = false // Don't run multiple simultaneous instances of this job

    def execute(context) {
        if(context.jobDetail.jobDataMap['recCounter'] == null) { context.jobDetail.jobDataMap['recCounter'] = 1 }
        else { context.jobDetail.jobDataMap['recCounter'] = context.jobDetail.jobDataMap['recCounter'] + 1 }

        println(context.jobDetail.jobDataMap['recCounter'])
}
```

The output when run is a new line with '1' every 5 seconds. It should be incrementing the counter each time.

```
1
1
1
1
etc..
```

I'm running Grails 3.3.9 and build.gradle has `compile "org.grails.plugins:grails-spring-websocket:2.4.1"` in dependencies

Thanks

Comment: what about `AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger()`?

Comment: @injecteer OK...I'm new to Grails & Java, how would I use that in the context of my code, please?

Answer (score 0):

I have never used `context` object in my apps, but a counter can be implemented in a straight-forward way:

```
class MyJob {
    //some static stuff

    AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger()

    def execute(context) {
        counter.incrementAndGet()    
        println counter.intValue()
    }
}
```

Comment: Great thanks. And that would persist between job executions you think?

Comment: it should. AFAIK the job instances are singletons for performance reasons and are not re-intsantiated upon each trigger